# jquery - colorbox plugin, I need to submit form via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, modal-dialog, colorbox

If I'm using the [colorbox plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/), how do I submit a form via ajax and then make a new modal out of the response? For example, the user clicks a link and a modal pops up. They fill out the form and click submit and then the modal should change to the next form. Then they fill out the next one etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to load the `<div id="cboxLoadedContent">` from the first colorbox invocation with the result of your ajax call:

```
$('#cboxLoadedContent').load('form-process.php', formData);
```

If the new form you're loading is a different size you should also call the colorbox resize() method to adjust the size of the modal:

```
$.colorbox.resize();
```